# Getting incorrect filepath inside custom block front-end output using @wordpress/create-block tutorial

Tags: plugin-development, images, javascript, urls, block-editor

I am following the official WordPress "Create a Block Tutorial" located here: https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/handbook/tutorials/create-block/

I used this as a starting point for the plugin: `npx @wordpress/create-block`

I am using it in conjunction with Local by Flywheel for my dev environment. Mostly everything seems to be working except when I try to include other files in the block's CSS like a custom font file or an image. This is part of the tutorial: https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/handbook/tutorials/create-block/block-code/

Example:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: Gilbert;
    src: url(./Gilbert-color.otf);
    font-weight: bold;
}
.wp-block-create-block-tdblocks {
    font-family: Gilbert;
    font-size: 64px;
    font-weight: bold;
    background-image: url(./map_bg.png);
    background-repeat: repeat;
}
```

So after I insert the recommended code and run `npm run build`, the css file generated by the build process leaves the links to these files relative to the current web page's URL and not a link to its file location in the proper plugin folder.

Here is what it gives me for the image file for instance (which shows as a 404 error naturally):

```
https://taylor-design-starter-theme.local/sample-page/images/map_bg.f0104819.png
```

I'd expect it to give me this:

```
https://taylor-design-starter-theme.local/wp-content/plugins/tdblocks/build/images/map_bg.f0104819.png
```

I have tried adjusting the "url" value in the scss file to see if that would help. Like `src: url(../map_bg.png);` or `src: url(map_bg.png);` and that didn't seem to do anything.

Am I missing something? Or is there a way to get it to use the plugin directory?

Thank you.

EDIT: Here is the CSS generated by the build process when I run `npm run build`

```
@font-face{font-family:Gilbert;font-weight:700;src:url(fonts/Gilbert-color.02d3d364.otf)}.wp-block-create-block-tdblocks{background-image:url(images/map_bg.f0104819.png);background-repeat:repeat;font-family:sans-serif;font-size:64px;font-weight:700}
```

Comment: Where did the `./` come from? I don't see it or the bg image in the linked tutorial

Comment: I copied some other examples I saw that did this. It was the same result either way for me.

Comment: absolute links would be bad practice as it means your block would be broken if you were in a sub-dir install or a subdomain install or installed WP in a subfolder. Likewise if the wp-content follder is custom or your plugin was renamed or installed in `plugins-mu` it would all break with absolute URLs

Comment: what does the built CSS actually say if you look at the source and ignore what the browser thinks it should be?

Comment: @TomJNowell Hi I added the CSS that is generated by the build process above.

Comment: @TomJNowell and yes, I was trying to avoid hard coding urls into anything. I was hoping the build process would just auto target the plugin folder without needing the root domain in it.

Comment: this CSS, are you loading the file or is it being inlined? What it's generated looks correct, and browsers are meant to interpret relative URLs relative to where the style is, not the address of the page itself

Comment: @TomJNowell so in the backend in the block editor screen, the image does show up with no 404 error. This css file is included with `<link rel="stylesheet" id="create-block-tdblocks-style-css" href="https://taylor-design-starter-theme.local/wp-content/plugins/tdblocks/build/style-index.css?ver=0.1.0" media="all">`

On the front end page view, it is being inlined in a set of `<style></style>` tags. Not a `<link rel="stylesheet" />` etc... tag.

Comment: backend CSS and frontend CSS are not the same, what you're using is expecting different stylesheets for both, you're going to have to provide a more comprehensive copy of your code rather than the limited sub-snippets to debug this. There's too much guess work trying to figure out what your save component looks like or your block registration, or your `block.json` to go back and forth, share the entire thing, that way I can diagnose the problem or reproduce it locally

Comment: @TomJNowell I've been scratching my head all day trying to figure this out, and I believe I might just be misunderstanding how this is supposed to work. I've uploaded a new test block I did from scratch: [github link](https://github.com/taylordesignchris/block-example). I found [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@wordpress/scripts#using-fonts-and-images) in the documentation and it seems as close to what I'm trying to do as I can find. I'm not sure I can get this to work on the front-end by only using `block.json` Thanks so much for helping me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WordPress is inlining the style as an optimisation:

> When a page gets rendered, stylesheets that have opted-in to get inlined get added to an array. Their size is retrieved using a filesize call (which is why the path data is necessary), and the array is then ordered by ascending size (smaller to larger stylesheet). We then start inlining these assets by going from smallest to largest, until a 20kb limit is reached.

https://make.wordpress.org/core/2021/07/01/block-styles-loading-enhancements-in-wordpress-5-8/

You have several options:

- raise this as a bug with Trac
- make your stylesheet bigger or add other stylesheets elsewhere that get inlined and reach the 20kb limit
- disable style inlining

```php
add_filter( 'styles_inline_size_limit', '__return_zero' );
```

Whatever you do, **you should still raise a bug ticket on WP core.** Specifically around inlining styles that have relative URLs.

I would also raise a bug on the Gutenberg Github too around `block.json` documenting as it would be best to have a way to use `block.json` and opt in or opt out, which doesn't appear to be possible without writing PHP filters. It's likely if you don't raise this issue, nobody will be aware of the problem and more things like this will be done.

Comment: Oh cool, thank you. I'll give some of this a try. I did see that other blocks did use PHP enqueue methods to do what I wanted in the area where you add `register_block_type();`, but like you said, it would be nice if you could just deal with this in `block.json`. I shall take a crack at filing a proper bug ticket and hope they don't ignore me haha.

Comment: I'd recommend `block.json` going forward, but it's frustrating to see this issue. It's well intentioned but doesn't account for all cases

Answer (score 0):

css will open the link where the page is, in this case is this one

https://taylor-design-starter-theme.local/sample-page/images

by adding ./image_name.png  is the same as saying to look in that directory by an image called "image_name.png".  if the image isnt there, it will not work.

i dont know how to give in css absolut path instead of an url, only in php.
However if you put your image in that path, wordpress/wp-content/plugins/tdblocks/build/images/  that is the same as the first url. it will work.
I know that it is not the answer desired, but it will work just fine.